# How To Send Mapped Values To State Properties After Dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently trying to set the mapped value into state value, in my code I have used 2 mapped functions wherein a select dropdown on click will trigger the 2nd props function,the first props function does send the value to its respective state however the 2nd props value goes blank into the state i have no idea why it would be really helpful if someone would help me in this problem thank you

Code :

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import {postData,getCode,getData} from "../actions/journal";
import {connect} from "react-redux"
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import "./css/JournalAdd.css"

 class JournalAdd extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super (props);
        this.state={
            code:'',
      head_of_account:'',
 };
this.onChange=this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.onCreate=this.onCreate.bind(this);
        this.handleDateChange=this.handleDateChange.bind(this);
        this.sendData=this.sendData.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getData();
        let journal2={
            code:this.state.code,
        }
        this.props.getCode(journal2)
    }

    sendData=e=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        let journal2={
code:this.state.code,
        }
        this.props.getCode(journal2)
    }

    onChange = event => {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]:event.target.value});
    };
    onCreate(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let journal2=
        { 
            code:this.state.code,
            head_of_account:this.state.head_of_account,


    };
    console.log(journal2);
    this.props.postData(journal2);
    this.setState({
        code:'',
        head_of_account:'',
    })
    }
    handleDateChange=date=>{
        this.setState({date:date});
    }
      render() {


          return (
              <div classname="masterfile-add">
                  <form className="masterfileadd-form">
                  <p><label className="masterfileadd-text">

                        Code : 
                         < select value={this.state.code}  onChange={this.onChange} name="code" className="jtextbox2" onClick={this.sendData}> 
                             {this.props.journal.map(journal => {  
                  return <option value={journal.code} name="code" >{journal.code}</option>
                             })} 
                   </select>

                        </label>

                      </p>
                      <p><label className="masterfileadd-text">
                          Account Head :

                             {this.props.journal1.map(journal1 => {  
                  return  <label value={this.state.head_of_account} onChange={this.onChange}className= "jtextbox3">{journal1.head_of_account}</label>
                             })} 
                      </label>               
                      </p>
                      </label></p>
                      <p className="jButton"><input type="submit" value="Submit"onChange={this.onChange} onClick={this.onCreate} className="jButtonAdd" /></p>
                  </form>

              </div>
          )
      }
}
const mapStateToProps=state=>({
    journal:state.journalReducer.journal,
    journal2:state.journalReducer.journal2,
    journal1:state.journalReducer.journal1,
    error:state.journalReducer.error
})
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,{postData,getData,getCode}
)(JournalAdd)
```

Comment: Please create a proper [mre]

Comment: sir i have reduced it to be a minimal reproducible example